# What files does Windows Server 2003 R2 Ent need to boot successfully?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2003-r2, bsod, windows

Help - I have a server which keeps rebooting. It brings up the Windows Server 2003 loading screen then reboots, continually.

This happens whether I use normal mode, safe mode or last known good.

I turned off auto-rebooting and got a BSOD with the message "Stop: 0x0000007b (oxf789ea94, 0xc000000e, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)"

I can boot from a Windows Server 2008 disc I have (but for some reason it won't boot from my Windows Server 2003 disc?) and go into the recovery console. I ran CHKDSK /F C: and this showed a number of problems which were allegedly corrected.

I'm leaning towards some system files being corrupted. I can mount the Server 2003 R2 CD as a folder (the server is some distance away; I'm using the HP ILO console) so I can expand and restore files from the CD.

So, what files should I restore?? Or, does anyone have any other suggestions for gathering more information on the root problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this an interrupted installation?

Comment: No, it is a production terminal server that has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying files from C:\Windows\Repair to C:\Windows\System32\Config seems to have got it going again! In some state, at least ... at least it is booting and usable now.

I backed up the files I copied over so I might try putting some back and seeing if I can find the most optimal set, then it may be prudent to reinstall service pack 2.

At least I've now been able to install the recovery console.